# how to give a generic value/id in HTTP request (path) in jmeter?

Tags: testing, automation, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-3.2

[The product id changes very time when the page refreshes so can you tell me how can one give a generic id/name which automatically picks the assigned id when the page is loaded.

Example
Currently what is happening:
In Path:        /EAPPFileUpload/UploadFiles?currentFolder=ARA&productID=1234

What is required
In Path         /EAPPFileUpload/UploadFiles?currentFolder=ARA&productID=variable

where variable shall possess the id in it.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcKaE.png)

Comment: Click on "1" to view the image for better understanding.

Comment: Please clarify your question

Answer (score 1):

My expectation is that this "product id"  doesn't come out of nowhere, most likely it exists somewhere in previous response, either in body, or in [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) or in [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL).

So you need to extract the value from the previous response with i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and replace hard-coded (recorded?) value of `1234` with the aforementioned JMeter Variable.

The whole process is known as **[correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter)** and has been discussed hundreds of times already.